# Using Multiple Carousels with CaroufredSel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel, caroufredsel

http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/50/

The carousel is a click/swipe drag slideshow and it uses the caroufresel.js.  I have multiple instances of this carousel, but when I click and drag one of the carousel, ALL the carousels move.  I believe its in the JavaScript, but I'm fairly new to this and I cant seem to figure this one out.

So what I want to do is separate each carousel to move individually.

```
<article class="wrapper">
<div class="caroufredsel">
<ul class="carousel">
<!--CONTENT-->
</ul>
</div>
</article>
```

This is basic structure and is used multiple times for multiple carousels.  Each one is differentiated by itself, but I'm having trouble with implementing the carousel for each one to respond individually.

The initial link at the top shows the original mark up and js.

Appreciate the responses.

Here's the javascript:

```
// the carousel
var $carousel = null;

// the draggable wrapper
var $wrapper = null;

// the width of one item
var itemWidth = 1280;

// the duration of the scrolling
var scrollDuration = 300;

// dragging-engine
var startDragPosition = false;
function startDrag( event ) {
event.preventDefault();

if ( $carousel.triggerHandler( 'isScrolling' ) ) {
startDragPosition = false;
return;
}
startDragPosition = event.pageX;
$wrapper.bind(
'mousemove',
function( e ) {
$wrapper.css({
'marginLeft': -(itemWidth + startDragPosition - e.pageX)
});
}
);
}
function stopDrag( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
$wrapper.unbind('mousemove');

if ( startDragPosition ) {
var currentDragPosition = event.pageX;
var direction = false;
if ( startDragPosition < currentDragPosition ) {
direction = 'prev';
} else if ( startDragPosition > currentDragPosition ) {
direction = 'next';
}
if ( direction ) {
$carousel.trigger( direction );
$wrapper.animate({
'marginLeft': -itemWidth
}, scrollDuration);
}
}
startDragPosition = false;
}

$(function() {

// the carousel
$carousel = $('.carousel');
$carousel.caroufredsel({
width: 1280 * 5,
height: 638,
align: false,
items: {
visible: 3,
start: -1
},
scroll: {
items: 1,
duration: scrollDuration
},
auto: false
});

// make the wrapper draggable
$wrapper = $carousel.parent();
$wrapper.css({
'cursor': 'move',
'marginLeft': -itemWidth
});
$wrapper.bind('mousedown', startDrag)
$wrapper.bind('mouseup', stopDrag)
$wrapper.bind('mouseleave', stopDrag);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what's going wrong as you haven't supplied the HTML for the carousels. But from what I can tell, you're defining the `var carousel` as anything having the class 'carousel'. Perhaps you need to give each carousel a unique ID and then initialise them separately?